# What is a “HIDE” system on F/A-18?

Tags: fa-18

On the ATC recording from [this video](https://youtu.be/sdI10nJSq5Q) a Blue Angels aircraft has declared emergency. When ATC asks for information about the problem the pilot responds, “one of our hide systems is malfunctioned and it prevents us from extending our gear normally. So we have to emergency extend the gear which forces us to take an arrested landing if able.”

What is a “hide” system? If that is in fact what they’re saying. That’s what the video transcribes it as and it could be wrong. Also, why would a failure cause emergency gear extension? And why does emergency extension force an arrested landing?

Comment: That last question maybe should be split off into a separate question. ??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Hyd" is slang for hydraulics. The landing gear is powered by one of the hydraulic systems, so if that system was down, the pilot wouldn't be able to extend the gear normally. The brakes are also powered by hydraulics—hence the need for an arrested landing.

Comment: Correct.  She’s referring either to HYD1 or HYD2, not ‘hide’.